# Calculator Clear button functionality isn't working as desired. set to 0 causes multiplication to = 0 . Desire AC to give same result as new start ups

Tags: java

/*/******

I stripped down as much as I thought possible while still being pleasing to use. this is my beginner calulator project. it shows result as I type. I'm using multiple textFields to achieve this. I'm open to smarter ways. for now though I would like to lie in my bed as I've made it to learn.

On fresh start up no issues with parsing and the getting a result but after clear lets say I used addButton last it will automatically add the first new number to itself then give me the result as the new num1. if I set num1 to 0; add works but not multiplication because of zero... is .setText(" "); really deleting the values? is there a better way? I've read all I could find on textFields.

I will happily take direction to the correct reading material in lieu of a direct answer. textField numbered slightly out of order. My apologies order is top down - 3 -2 -1 -4 -5.  4 and 5 are to help me visualize the problem 3 shows the work, 2 the result and 1 is used for parsing num1 and setting the current result to num1 so I can chain the addition.
I've tried parsing at different locations setting num1 to 0 setting result to the remainder of result and num1 to be the new num2.. and a bunch of other silly attempts at similar solulutions. I know that my if(numberButtons[i]) { statement directly above the switch for + - * / where it sets num2=Double.parseDouble(textField4.getText()); is the main cause but it is also the only way I know to give constant results as I type in my numbers.
I,ve tried more thought-out and many more arbitrary changes to my code trying to understand what's really going on and what's possible.
Afer 3 weeks I am embarrassed for myself. Thank you for your time. Again even just the right direction will help me very much. I do like and desire to solve the problem on my own. I am just truly out of my depth as I am 3 months into this a few hours a day in my time off of work. I truly enjoy it and would love to have a sense of closure and completion to this problem.
*//*/*************

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Calc1 implements ActionListener {
    
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField3,textField2,textField1,textField4,textField5; 
    JButton[] numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    JButton[] functionButtons = new JButton[6];
    JButton addButton,subButton,multiButton,diviButton,decimalButton;
    JButton equalButton,deleteButton,clearButton,negativeButton;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;
    Font myFont = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD,31);
    Font font1 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 30);
    Font font2 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 28);
    Font font3 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 48);
    Font font4 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 65);
    double num1=0,num2=0,result=0;
    char operator;

    Calc1(){
        Border border1 = new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 4, true);
        frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setOpacity(1);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setBounds(201, 60, 323, 700);
                
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(5, 4, 300, 52);
        label.setFont(font1);
        label.setVisible(true);
        label.setText("Calculator");
        label.setForeground(Color.blue);
        label.setFont(new Font("Console", 1, 17));
        label.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        
        Border border = new LineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 7, true);
        textField3 = new JTextField(); 
        textField3.setBounds(5,54, 299, 38);
        textField3.setFont(font2);
        textField3.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        textField3.setBorder(border);
        textField3.setOpaque(true);
        textField3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        textField3.setFocusable(true);
    
        textField2 = new JTextField(); 
        textField2.setBounds(5, 89, 299, 44); 
        textField2.setFont(myFont);
        textField2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        textField2.setBorder(border);
        textField2.setVisible(true);
        textField2.setOpaque(true);
        textField2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        textField2.setFocusable(false);
        
        textField1 = new JTextField(); 
        textField1.setBounds(5,510, 300, 35); 
        textField1.setFont(myFont);
        textField1.setVisible(true);
    
        textField4 = new JTextField(); 
        textField4.setBounds(5,549, 300, 35); 
        textField4.setFont(myFont);
        textField4.setVisible(true);
        
        textField5 = new JTextField(); 
        textField5.setBounds(5,580, 300, 35); 
        textField5.setFont(myFont);
        textField5.setVisible(true);
            
        addButton = new JButton("+");
        subButton = new JButton("-");
        multiButton = new JButton("x");
        diviButton = new JButton("÷");
        decimalButton = new JButton(".");
        equalButton = new JButton("=");
        deleteButton = new JButton("←");
        clearButton = new JButton("AC");

        functionButtons[0] = addButton; 
        functionButtons[1] = subButton;
        functionButtons[2] = multiButton;
        functionButtons[3] = diviButton;
        functionButtons[4] = decimalButton;
        functionButtons[5] = clearButton;
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
            functionButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            functionButtons[i].setFont(myFont);
            functionButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
            functionButtons[i].setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));  
        }   
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            numberButtons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            numberButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            numberButtons[i].setFont(font2);
            numberButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
        }   
        panel = new JPanel(); 
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4,4,4));   
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBorder(border1);
        panel.setBounds(4, 133, 300, 300);
        
        panel.add(numberButtons[7]);
        panel.add(numberButtons[8]);
        panel.add(numberButtons[9]);
        panel.add(addButton);
        panel.add(numberButtons[4]);
        panel.add(numberButtons[5]);
        panel.add(numberButtons[6]);
        panel.add(subButton);
        panel.add(numberButtons[1]);
        panel.add(numberButtons[2]);
        panel.add(numberButtons[3]);
        panel.add(multiButton);
        panel.add(decimalButton);
        panel.add(numberButtons[0]);
        panel.add(clearButton);
        panel.add(diviButton);
        frame.add(panel); 
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(textField3);
        frame.add(textField2); 
        frame.add(textField1);
        frame.add(textField4);
        frame.add(textField5);
        
        frame.setOpacity(1);
        frame.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        label.setForeground(Color.blue);
        label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        label.setOpaque(true);  
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calc1 calc = new Calc1();   
    }
    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { 
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[i]) { 
                textField1.setText(textField1.getText().concat(String.valueOf((i))));
                textField3.setText(textField3.getText().concat(String.valueOf((i))));   
                textField4.setText(textField4.getText().concat(String.valueOf((i))));   
                textField5.setText(textField5.getText().concat(String.valueOf((i))));
            }
        }
            if (e.getSource()==subButton) {     
                num1=Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
                operator='-';
                textField3.setText(textField3.getText().concat("-"));
                textField4.setText("");
                textField4.setText(textField4.getText().concat(""));    
         }
            if (e.getSource()==addButton) { 
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
                operator = '+';
                textField3.setText(textField3.getText().concat("+"));
                textField4.setText("");
                textField4.setText(textField4.getText().concat(""));
         }
            if (e.getSource()==multiButton) {
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
                operator = '*';
                textField3.setText(textField3.getText().concat("x"));
                textField4.setText("");
                textField4.setText(textField4.getText().concat(""));    
        }
            if (e.getSource()==diviButton) {
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
                operator = '/';
                textField3.setText(textField3.getText().concat("÷"));
                textField4.setText("");
                textField4.setText(textField4.getText().concat(""));
        }   
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { 
                if(e.getSource()==numberButtons[i]) {   
                    num2=Double.parseDouble(textField4.getText());
                
                    switch(operator) {
                    case'-':    
                        result=num1-num2;
                        textField1.setText(String.valueOf(result)); 
                        textField5.setText(String.valueOf(num1));   
                        break;
                    case'+':        
                        result=num1+num2;       
                        textField1.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                        textField5.setText(String.valueOf(num1));       
                        break;
                    case'*':
                        result=num1*num2;   
                        textField1.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                        textField5.setText(String.valueOf(num1));   
                        break;
                    case'/':
                        result=num1/num2; 
                        textField1.setText(String.valueOf(result)); 
                        textField5.setText(String.valueOf(num1));   
                        break;  
                     }
                }       
            textField2.setText(String.valueOf((result)));       
        }
        if (e.getSource()==clearButton) {   
            textField3.setText("");
            textField2.setText("");
            textField1.setText("");
            textField4.setText("");
            textField5.setText(""); 
        }       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you clear all your **JTextField**s, You should also reset all member variables used in previous calculations. After all, beacause of their scope (class global), they will still be holding values unless reset:

```
if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {   
    textField3.setText("");
    textField2.setText("");
    textField1.setText("");
    textField4.setText("");
    textField5.setText(""); 
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
    result = 0;
    operator = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. the operator = '\0'; part is exactly what I was missing. It makes sense.